# Python code for Adding tag in xml where parent tag is multiple with different attributes

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm parsing the following XML file using `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
              <sub-inner>
        <inner>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <inner id="500">
              <sub-inner>
                 <inside> 500 </inside>
              <sub-inner>
        <inner>
    </stream>
</main>
```

How do I insert `<outer>200</outer>` element into the < sub-inner>  tag where stream id ="2" one?

Answer (score 2):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring('''
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner>500</inner>
    </stream>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <inner>500</inner>
    </stream>
</main>''')
stream = root.find('.//stream[@id="2"]')
outer = ET.SubElement(stream, 'outer')
outer.text = '200'
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

output:

```
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner>500</inner>
    </stream>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <inner>500</inner>
    <outer>200</outer></stream>
</main>
```

---

If you want `outer` to come before the `inner`:

```
...
stream = root.find('.//stream[@id="2"]')
outer = ET.Element('outer')
outer.text = '200'
stream.insert(0, outer)
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

output:

```
<main>
    <stream id="1" name="some">
        <inner>500</inner>
    </stream>
    <stream id="2" name="some">
        <outer>200</outer><inner>500</inner>
    </stream>
</main>
```